# Opening attachments from Mail in iOS4 app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I got how to open attachments in your app from the Mail app [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application).

But how do I handle this in an iOS4 app? When my app is in the background and I open a file from Mail, `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` does not fire.  `-applicationDidBecomeActive` does, but it does not seem to have a way to retrieve the link to the file from there.

Anyone encountered this before? Any additional pointers on pitfalls I have yet to encounter will be very helpful too. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {

    if ([url isFileURL])
    {

        NSLog(@"file at path %@", [url path ]);
                // do something with your file
                return YES;
        }
        return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. For iOS 4.2, `application:handleOpenURL:` seem to be deprecated in favor of  `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`, but I guess I still need to implement it to support iOS 3.2.